# How is this interface code compiling in Java?

Tags: java, lombok

I wrote the following interface:

```
public interface Configuration
{
    String getClientId();
    void setClientId(String clientId);
}
```

and the following class

```
public class MyConfiguration implements Configuration
{
    @Getter
    private UUID clientId;

    @Override
    public void setClientId(String clientId)
    {
        this.clientId = UUID.fromString(clientId);
    }
}
```

As you can see, my `clientId` in `MyConfiguration` is a `UUID` whereas the interface is a String type. I was expecting a compiler error but how is this working?

Comment: Your private variable does not have to conform to the interface, only your method signature does. `void setClientId(String clientId)`

Answer (score 0):

But it.. doesn't compile:

```
> cat Test.java
interface Configuration {
    String getX();
}

class MyConfiguration implements Configuration {
    @lombok.Getter java.util.UUID x;
}

> javac -cp lombok.jar Test.java
Test.java:5: error: MyConfiguration is not abstract and does not override abstract method getX() in Configuration
class MyConfiguration implements Configuration {
^
Test.java:6: error: getX() in MyConfiguration cannot implement getX() in Configuration
    @lombok.Getter java.util.UUID x;
    ^
  return type UUID is not compatible with String
2 errors
```

If on your system it does, you're not compiling what you think you are compiling; you're certainly not compiling those exact two lines.

- Check if the `Configuration` in your `MyConfiguration.class` is referencing the Configuration you think it is (perhaps there is a second Configuration interface?)
- Do a project clean
- Check if perhaps you *did* write `public String getClientId()` in your code file: If you did, lombok will see it and then just not generate a getter as it is already there. However, if `@Getter` on a field ends up being a noop, lombok will emit a warning, so one way to ensure this isn't the case is to check for warnings.

If you're wondering what lombok is doing under the hood, there is always:

```
> java -jar lombok.jar delombok -p Test.java

[elided: The same compiler errors show up here too]
// Generated by delombok at Sat Apr 17 16:25:58 CEST 2021

interface Configuration {
    String getX();
}

class MyConfiguration implements Configuration {
    java.util.UUID x;

    @java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all")
    public java.util.UUID getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
}
```